How To All Images And Videos Get Folder Wise In Our App In Android Kotlin?
All images and video not show in folder wise
i want all images and video show folder wise and working very smooth working in application
application in all images and video show but not show with folder so i want folder with images and video

Add permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

If you're targeting Android 11 or higher, add:
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Now check permissions in the app:
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_CODE
    )
}

Create a data class called MediaFile:
data class MediaFile(val id: Long, val name: String, val mimeType: String, val path: String)

Read Media Files using ContentResolver:
fun getMediaFiles(contentResolver: ContentResolver): List<MediaFile> {
    val mediaFiles = mutableListOf<MediaFile>()
    val uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")

    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
    )

    val selection = (MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
            + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
            + " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
            + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)

    val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null)

    cursor?.use {
        val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID)
        val nameColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val mimeTypeColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE)
        val pathColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)

        while (it.moveToNext()) {
            val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
            val name = it.getString(nameColumn)
            val mimeType = it.getString(mimeTypeColumn)
            val path = it.getString(pathColumn)

            mediaFiles.add(MediaFile(id, name, mimeType, path))
        }
    }
    return mediaFiles
}

Sort Files by folder:
fun groupFilesByFolder(mediaFiles: List<MediaFile>): Map<String, List<MediaFile>> {
    return mediaFiles.groupBy { file ->
        File(file.path).parent ?: "Unknown"
    }
}

Note: Please add notes and debug points to gain a good understanding of how things work.

Companion Object
var folderList : ArrayList<FolderImgItem> = ArrayList()
var folderList2 : ArrayList<FoldervideoItem> = ArrayList()

Data Class
data class ImageModel(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val path: String
): Serializable
data class FolderImgItem(
    val folderName: String,
    val folderPath: String,
    val folderDate: String,
    val imageModels: ArrayList<ImageModel> = ArrayList(),
)
data class VideoModel(
    val id: Long,
    val path: String
): Serializable
data class FoldervideoItem(
    var folderName: String,
    var folderPath: String,
    var folderDate: String? = null,
    var VideoModels: ArrayList<VideoModel> = ArrayList<VideoModel>()
) : Serializable
        

images Get
object GalleryImageUtils {
        fun getAllImages(context: Context): List<ImageModel> {
    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
    )

    val collectionUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        // Query all the device storage volumes instead of the primary only
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    }

    val imagesList = mutableListOf<ImageModel>()

    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        collectionUri,
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        "${ MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"
    )

    cursor?.use {


        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        val uriColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val dNameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
            val uri = cursor.getString(uriColumn)
            val dName = cursor.getString(dNameColumn)

            val image = ImageModel(id,dName, uri)
            imagesList.add(image)
        }
    }

    return imagesList
}


fun getFolderList(arrayList: ArrayList<ImageModel>): ArrayList<FolderImgItem> {
    var ftime = true
    val arrayList2: ArrayList<FolderImgItem> = ArrayList<FolderImgItem>()

    if (arrayList != null && arrayList.isNotEmpty()) {

        for (i in arrayList.indices) {

            val file: File = File(arrayList[i].path)
            Log.d("====", "getFolderList:file ${file}")

            val parent = file.parent
            Log.d("====", "getFolderList:parent ${parent}")

            val parentFile = file.parentFile
            Log.d("====", "getFolderList:parentFile ${parentFile}")

            val filedate = parentFile.lastModified().toString()
            Log.d("====", "getFolderList:filedate ${filedate}")

            val name = parentFile.name
            Log.d("====", "getFolderList:name ${name}")

            if (!isFileExits(arrayList2, parent)) {
                arrayList2.add(FolderImgItem(name, parent, filedate))
            } else {
                if (name == "0") {
                    if (ftime) {
                        arrayList2.add(FolderImgItem(name, parent, filedate))
                        ftime = false
                    }
                }
            }
            val it: Iterator<FolderImgItem> = arrayList2.iterator()
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                val next: FolderImgItem = it.next()
                if (next.folderPath.equals(parent)) {
                    next.imageModels.add(arrayList[i])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList2
}

fun isFileExits(list: ArrayList<FolderImgItem>, str: String?): Boolean {
    val it: Iterator<FolderImgItem> = list.iterator()
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().folderPath.contains(str!!)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

Videos Get
object GalleryVideoUtils {

    fun getAllVideo(context: Context): List<VideoModel> {
        val VideoList = mutableListOf<VideoModel>()
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED} DESC"
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        )

        cursor?.use {

            val idColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)
            val uriColumn = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
            Log.d("GalleryApp", "------------------------- ${it.count}")
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                val id = it.getLong(idColumn)
                val uri = it.getString(uriColumn)
                Log.d("GalleryApp", "Image ID: $id, Image URI: $uri")
                VideoList.add(VideoModel(id, uri))
            }
        }
        return VideoList
    }


    fun getVideoFolderList(arrayList: ArrayList<VideoModel>): ArrayList<FoldervideoItem> {
        var ftime = true
        val arrayList2: ArrayList<FoldervideoItem> = ArrayList<FoldervideoItem>()

        if (arrayList != null && arrayList.isNotEmpty()) {

            for (i in arrayList.indices) {

                val file: File = File(arrayList[i].path)
                Log.d("====", "getFolderList:file ${file}")

                val parent = file.parent
                Log.d("====", "getFolderList:parent ${parent}")

                val parentFile = file.parentFile
                Log.d("====", "getFolderList:parentFile ${parentFile}")

                val filedate = parentFile.lastModified().toString()
                Log.d("====", "getFolderList:filedate ${filedate}")

                val name = parentFile.name
                Log.d("====", "getFolderList:name ${name}")

                if (!isFileExits(arrayList2, parent)) {
                    arrayList2.add(FoldervideoItem(name, parent, filedate))
                } else {
                    if (name == "0") {
                        if (ftime) {
                            arrayList2.add(FoldervideoItem(name, parent, filedate))
                            ftime = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                val it: MutableIterator<FoldervideoItem> = arrayList2.iterator()
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    val next: FoldervideoItem = it.next()
                    if (next.folderPath.equals(parent)) {
                        next.VideoModels.add(arrayList[i])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList2
    }

    fun isFileExits(list: ArrayList<FoldervideoItem>, str: String?): Boolean {
        val it: MutableIterator<FoldervideoItem> = list.iterator()
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().folderPath.contains(str!!)) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

Folder Images Show Activity
class FolderImgActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)

        var images = GalleryImageUtils.getAllImages(this@FolderImgActivity)

        folderList = getFolderList(images as ArrayList<ImageModel>)
        Log.d("====", "onCreate:images ${images}")

        val adapter = FolderImgAdapter(this@FolderImgActivity, folderList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }
}

folder show adapter
class FolderImgAdapter(var mainactivity: Context, private var folderItemList: List<FolderImgItem>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FolderImgAdapter.ImageViewHolder>() {

    class ImageViewHolder(val binding: ItemFolderBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemFolderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ImageViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(folderItemList[position].imageModels[0].path.toString()).centerCrop().into(holder.binding.imageView)
        holder.binding.fname.text = folderItemList[position].folderName
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            mainactivity.startActivity(
                Intent(mainactivity, ImageDataActivity::class.java).putExtra(
                    "position",
                    position
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return folderItemList.size
    }
}

folder in show all image
class ImageDataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagedata)
    
            val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    
            recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
    
            var pos = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)
            var images = folderList[pos].imageModels
            Log.d("====", "onCreate:images ${images}")
    
            val adapter = ImageAdapter(this@ImageDataActivity, images)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }

folder in image show adapter
class ImageAdapter(
        var activity: ImageDataActivity,
        private var images: java.util.ArrayList<ImageModel>
    ) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder>() {
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
            val view =
                LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false)
            return ImageViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
            Glide.with(holder.itemView)
                .load(images[position].path.toString())
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView)
    
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                activity.startActivity(
                    Intent(activity, ShowImageActivity::class.java)
                        .putExtra("images", images)
                        .putExtra("position", position)
                )
            }
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return images.size
        }
    
        class ImageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        }
    }

view pager with show activity
class ShowImageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityShowImageBinding
    lateinit var mydatabase: Mydatabase

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_show_image)

        mydatabase = Mydatabase(this)

        val imageList = intent.getSerializableExtra("images") as ArrayList<ImageModel>
        val position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)

        var myViewPager = MyViewPagerAdepter(this@ShowImageActivity, imageList)
        binding.pager.adapter = myViewPager
        binding.pager.currentItem = position
        if (mydatabase.isExists(imageList.get(position).path)) {
            binding.fev.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24)
        } else {
            binding.fev.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24)
        }

        binding.pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels)
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                binding.pager.currentItem = position
                if (mydatabase.isExists(imageList.get(position).path)) {
                    binding.fev.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24)
                } else {
                    binding.fev.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24)
                }
            }
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
            }
        })

        binding.fev.setOnClickListener {
            val img = imageList.get(binding.pager.currentItem)
            if (mydatabase.isExists(img.path)) {
                mydatabase.deletecontact(img.path)
                binding.fev.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_border_24)
            }else {
                mydatabase.InsertData(img.id.toString(), img.name, img.path)
                binding.fev.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_favorite_24)
            }
        }

    }
}

view pager adapter
class MyViewPagerAdepter(var context: Context, var imageList: ArrayList<ImageModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewPagerAdepter.MyViewHolderClass>() {
    class MyViewHolderClass(val binding: PageviwerimageBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): MyViewHolderClass {
        val binding =
            PageviwerimageBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MyViewHolderClass(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewPagerAdepter.MyViewHolderClass, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.seefullimage.setImageURI(imageList.get(position).path.toUri())
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = imageList.size
}

data base
class Mydatabase(
    var page: Context,
) : SQLiteOpenHelper(page, "stor.db", null, 1) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        var mytable =
            "Create Table Usersave (Id text primary key , NAME text, PATH text)"
        db!!.execSQL(mytable)

    }


    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    }

    fun InsertData(id: String, name: String, path: String): Boolean {
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put("ID", id)       // Insert the ID
            put("NAME", name)   // Insert the Name
            put("PATH", path)   // Insert the Path
        }

        val result = writableDatabase.insert("Usersave", null, contentValues)
        return result != -1L  // Returns true if insert was successful, false otherwise
    }


    fun isExists(path: String): Boolean {
        
        val cursor2 = readableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Usersave WHERE PATH = ?", arrayOf(path))

        if (cursor2.count > 0) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false

        }
    }

    // not use but all like image show this time use
//    fun ViewrMyconatct(userid: Int): Cursor {
//        var ss = "select * From Usersave where Userid = '$userid'"
//        var cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(ss, null);
//        return cursor
//    }

    fun deletecontact(path: String) {
        writableDatabase.execSQL("delete  FROM Usersave WHERE PATH = ?", arrayOf(path))
    }
}


Please include any relevant code snippets within your question, rather than providing them in your answer.
